# eth0 IP in the docker IPs range

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

One of the machines where we need to deploy docker containers has an eth0 IP set to within the docker IPs range (172.17.0.1/16).

The problem is that when we try to access this server through NAT from outside (SSH etc), then everything "hangs". I guess the packets get missdirected by the docker iptables rules.

What is the recommendation in this case if we cannot change the eth0 IP?

Comment: Have you tried this: [Customize the docker0 bridge](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/)?

Comment: @tgogos: that is what I was considering, but do the iptables rules automatically adapt or do I have to fiddle with it?

Comment: I've also found this relevant question: [Configuring Docker to not use the 172.17.0.0 range](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-use-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range) which you might find useful. Regarding the iptable rules, I think it's the docker daemon's job not yours. Changes will take effect after you restart it.

Comment: Thanks for the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker should avoid subnet collisions if it sees all of the in use subnets when it creates it's networks. However if you change networks (e.g. a laptop), then you want to setup address pools for docker to use. Steps for this are in my slides here: 
https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018eu/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#19

The important details are to setup a /etc/docker/daemon.json file containing:

```
{
  "bip": "10.15.0.0/24",
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base": "10.20.0.0/16", "size": 24},
    {"base": "10.40.0.0/16", "size": 24}
  ]
}
```

Adjust the ip ranges as needed. Stop all containers in the bad networks, delete the containers, delete any user created networks, restart the docker engine, and then recreate any user created networks and containers (often the last two steps just involves removing and redeploying a compose project or swarm stack).

---

Note, it wasn't clear if you were attempting to connect to your host or container. You should not be connecting directly to a container IP externally (with very few exceptions). Instead you publish the desired ports that you need to be able to access externally, and you connect to the host IP on that published port to reach the container. E.g.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Will start nginx with it's normal port 80 inside the container that you normally cannot reach externally. Publishing host port 8080 (could just as easily be 80 to match the container port) maps connections to the container port 80.

One important prerequisite is the application inside the container must listen on all interfaces, not just 127.0.0.1, to be able to access it from outside of that container's network namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was talking about connections to the host (not the containers), I'm well aware on how to publish containers ports to the host. For example one issue we had was SSH to the host not working through external NAT after docker installation.